# Accessing Telephoto lens using Camera2 or CameraX in S21 ultra

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I’m trying to access telephoto lens on Samsung S21 ultra using Camera2 and CameraX API. It list down two back and two front cameras. See in snapshot attached. But none of these is Telephoto lens. Two cameras accessible via APIs are WIDE and UW lens but Telephoto and Periscope Telephoto are missing.

Can someone confirm if Samsung S21 Ultra telephoto camera is opened to be used in third party apps and can be accessed via Camera2 APIs?

I was also thinking of binding multiple physical cameras to a single logical camera and we can access them but while trying to retrieve physical camera ids from logical cameras. However I’m always getting null value when printing these. See code snippet below.

```
fun findDualCameras(manager: CameraManager, facing: Int? = null): Array<DualCamera> {
val dualCameras = ArrayList<DualCamera>()
// Iterate over all the available camera characteristics
manager.cameraIdList.map {
    Pair(manager.getCameraCharacteristics(it), it)
}.filter {
    // Filter by cameras facing the requested direction
    facing == null || it.first.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == facing
}.filter {
    // Filter by logical cameras
    it.first.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES)!!.contains(
        CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA
    )
}.forEach {
    // All possible pairs from the list of physical cameras are valid results
    // NOTE: There could be N physical cameras as part of a logical camera grouping
    val physicalCameras = it.first.physicalCameraIds.toTypedArray()
    for (idx1 in physicalCameras.indices) {
        for (idx2 in (idx1 + 1) until physicalCameras.size) {
            dualCameras.add(
                DualCamera(
                    it.second, physicalCameras[idx1], physicalCameras[idx2]
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
return dualCameras.toTypedArray()
}
```

Is there any other possibility to access the Telescope camera directly in S21 ultra or Can we get stream from telescope camera indirectly in S21 ultra?

[image: Result]